# Select one combo box value on the basis of another combo box value

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I am new to WPF application development. I want to get floors on the basis of blocks. I have one combo box of blocks and another combo box of floors. When I select any block in one combo box, the other combo box should display the floors of the select block.
This is the combo box layout:

[image]

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="100"
          Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="35"
          Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded"
          SelectedValuePath ="Id"
          SelectedValue ="{Binding SelectedBlockId, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}"  />

<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Width="100"
          Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="35"
          Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded"
          SelectedValuePath ="Id"
          SelectedValue ="{Binding SelectedFloorId, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Floors}"  />
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing some code on your question.... like `Selector_OnSelectionChanged()`

Comment: private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer to the following blog post for an example of how to implement cascading ComboBoxes in WPF using the MVVM pattern: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/17/cascading-comboboxes-in-wpf-using-mvvm/

You could basically just replace the Countries and the Cities types from the sample code with your Block and Floor types.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different example.

Xaml...

```
<!-- language: xaml -->
<Label Name="FavoriteFoodLbl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="13">Favorite Food</Label>
<ComboBox Name="FavoriteFoodCombo" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="13" ItemsSource="{Binding Foods}" SelectedItem="{Binding FavoriteFood, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<Label Name="FavoriteFlavourLbl" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="13">Favorite Flavour</Label>
<ComboBox Name="FavoriteFlavourCombo" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="13" ItemsSource="{Binding Flavours}"  />
```

View model/code-behind code...

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Foods { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Pizza", "Ice Cream", "Soup" };

    private string _favoriteFood;
    public string FavoriteFood
    {
        get { return _favoriteFood; }
        set
        {
            _favoriteFood = value;
            switch (_favoriteFood)
            {
                case "Pizza":
                    _flavours = new ObservableCollection<string>(PizzaToppings);
                    break;
                case "Ice Cream":
                    _flavours = new ObservableCollection<string>(IceCreamFlavours);
                    break;
                case "Soup":
                    _flavours = new ObservableCollection<string>(SoupFlavours);
                    break;
                default:
                    _flavours = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                    break;
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FavoriteFood"));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Flavours"));
        }
    }

    public List<string> PizzaToppings { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "Margarita", "Pepperoni", "Meat Feast" };
    public List<string> IceCreamFlavours { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "Vanilla", "Strawberry", "Chocolate" };
    public List<string> SoupFlavours { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "Tomato", "Leek and Potato", "Chicken" };

    private ObservableCollection<string> _flavours = null;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Flavours
    {
        get
        {
            return _flavours;
        }
        set
        {
            _flavours = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string FavoriteFlavour { get; set; }
```

Change out the case statement for something appropriate.
Does this help?

Comment: I am using MVVM, so kindly answer me according to MVVM architecture

Comment: That code should work in your view model. Does it not?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to establish master-detail relationship between `Block` and `Floor` models and correctly bind them to you View (comboboxes).

So supposing your `Floor` and `Block` have two properties `ID` and `Description`, your model should look like this:

```
public class Floor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Block
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }
    // notice Floors collection inside each block
    public IList<Floor> Floors { get; set; }

    public Block()
    {
        Floors = new List<Floor>();
    }
}
```

Your ViewModel will contain two `ObservableCollection`s and one property to store currently selected block. Notice `SelectedBlock` property setter: when the property is updated, the `Floors` collection gets recreated with new values.

```
public const string BlocksPropertyName = "Blocks";
private ObservableCollection<Block> _blocks = null;
public ObservableCollection<Block> Blocks
{
    get
    {
        return _blocks;
    }
    set
    { 
        _blocks = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(BlocksPropertyName);
    }
}

public const string SelectedBlockPropertyName = "SelectedBlock";
private Block _selectedBlock = null;
public Block SelectedBlock
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedBlock;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedBlock = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedBlockPropertyName);

        if (_selectedBlock != null)
        {
            Floors = new ObservableCollection<Floor>(_selectedBlock.Floors);
        }
    }
}

public const string FloorsPropertyName = "Floors";
private ObservableCollection<Floor> _floors = null;
public ObservableCollection<Floor> Floors
{
    get
    {
        return _floors;
    }
    set
    {
        _floors = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(FloorsPropertyName);
    }
}
```

In your XAML you just bind both ComboBoxes to corrispective collections:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBlock}" />

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Floors}" />
```